# Reference request: Random telegraph signals.

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I came across a type of random process earlier with the structure
$$
X(t) = (-1)^{N(t)}Y,\ t\geqslant 0
$$
where $\{N(t):t\geqslant 0\}$ is a homogeneous Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and $Y$ is a symmetric Rademacher random variable, i.e. $\mathbb P(Y=1)=1/2 = \mathbb P(Y=-1)$ independent of $\{N(t)\}$. It was called a *random telegraph signal.* Obviously $X(t)=\pm 1$ as according to the number of jumps in the Poisson process and $Y$ determines the value of $X(0)$.

Searching for "random telegraph signal," I could not find anything related to this type of process. I'm interested in literature (textbooks or papers) that study this process and its generalizations in more detail, but I do not know what to search for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraph_process

Comment: theres quite a few links to other pages there too

Comment: search for "arxiv" and "random telegraph signal" ; and in google.books. search for "random telegraph signal" .  Both yield plenty.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I saw the Wikipedia article, but it didn't seem to be describing the same type of process.

Comment: @kimchilover I did a quick search on arXiv and didn't find anything relevant. Perhaps there is a different name by which I should be searching?

Comment: Tons of references... https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-36852-3 is a classic. Papers by Balakrishnan, the review article by Bena  https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0606116

Comment: I also need a reference regarding telegraph processes. Could I ask you to look into [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503676/telegraph-vs-bernoulli-processes)?